# How-to dispose a waithandle correctly

Tags: c#, waithandle

I'm doing some multi-threading and use AutoResetEvents and ManualResetEvents do control my main - loop. When "destryoing" the threads I also have to dispose these signals, that's clear.

But I saw different ways how to dispose Waithandles, and I'm not sure which one is correct:

Version 1

```
if (disposing)
{
 this.threadExitEvent.SafeWaitHandle.Dispose();
 this.threadExitEvent.Close();
 this.threadExitEvent = null;
 ....
}
```

Version 2

```
if (disposing)
{
 this.threadExitEvent.Close();
 this.threadExitEvent = null;
 ....
}
```

Version 3

```
if (disposing)
{
 this.threadExitEvent.Close();
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 2 is what I'd go with, as there's (presumably) no need to hang on to your newly-disposed `WaitHandle`, so setting it to `null` is a good idea. This also makes it easier to adapt your object being able to recover from being disposed, as all you have to do is check to see if the `WaitHandle` is null and recreate it if so.

That being said, nobody's going to slap your hand for going with option 3.

Don't use option 1; it's generally a bad idea to "reach inside" of objects and start disposing members. Calling `Close` (since the `Dispose` method from `IDisposable` is explicitly implemented and has identical code to `Close`) automatically takes care of disposing of the `SafeWaitHandle`. Don't do that yourself.

Comment: + 1 - I completely overlooked the fact that Dispose is an explicit interface implementation (thanks, Adam!) - this is certainly the way to go.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I already guessed that version 2 is the "cleanest" one. Thanks